# How to connect to a oauth2 server from android using Account Manager

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, accountmanager

I have a spring oauth2 server in my backend which issues the access and refresh token when a user login request comes with the client and user credentials.Now i want to connect to this oauth2 server from my android application using the Account manager in android.I have searched a lot for that but found everything that connect to google auth server using google api.How can i connect to my own oauth server using this account manager and can retrieve the token and can handle the token expiry and password change.Somebody please help me to solve this.

Comment: looks like no one has any kind of answers for this question.....

Answer (score 0):

Check this tutorial, maybe offer you the answer:

http://blog.udinic.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/

"First time logging-in

The app asks the AccountManager for an auth-token.

The AccountManager asks the relevant AccountAuthenticator if it has a token for us.

Since it has none (there’s no logged-in user), it show us a AccountAuthenticatorActivity that will allow the user to log-in.

The user logs-in and auth-token is returned from the server.

The auth-token is stored for future use in the AccountManager.

The app gets the auth-token it requested

Everyone’s happy!

In case the user has already logged-in, we would get the auth-token back already on the second step. You can read more about authenticating using OAuth2 here."

I found this article looking for exactly the same problem.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).